# what is Unit Testing MVC4 Response Status Code

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, httpcontext

I have a unit test that test route with too many segments, but I'd like to extend it to test `Response Status Code` (which should return 404 code).

Is it possible to use that mocked httpContext and check a status code?

`HttpContextMock.Object.Response.StatusCode` always returns 0 status code (due to mocking just one part of `HttpContext` I suppose).

```
[TestMethod]
public void RouteWithTooManySegments()
{
    var routes = new RouteCollection();
    MyApp.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);

    var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var httpResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

    httpContextMock.Setup(c => c.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath)
        .Returns("~/dawd/dawdaw/dawdaw/daw");

    RouteData routeData = routes.GetRouteData(httpContextMock.Object);

    Assert.IsNull(routeData);
}
```

Using `ErrorController` to return status code "404" in the view and appropriate `Response Status Code`:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }
}
```

and `Web.Config` rules

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
 </httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below Unit Test would verify the HttpStatusCode would set to 404. *Note it must be set in your Controller's Action as you have in your question. If you expect the Web.config to interact it is more of a web integration test, which is completely a different test.*

```
[TestMethod]
public void RouteWithTooManySegments()
{
    var httpContextStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var httpResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var controllerContextStub = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

    httpContextStub.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(httpResponseMock.Object);
    controllerContextStub.Setup(x => x.HttpContext)
        .Returns(httpContextStub.Object);

    var sut = new ErrorController
        { ControllerContext = controllerContextStub.Object };

    sut.NotFound();

    httpResponseMock.VerifySet(x => x.StatusCode = 404);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking more in direction of a web integration test.